# Unable to enter data into database using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am not able to enter data into my database. Please help and let me know what's wrong with my code.

```
    <?php
    require("dbconn.php");
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $fname = $_POST['fname'];
        $lname = $_POST['lname'];
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['pass1'];
        $hash = crypt($password);
        $admin = 0;
        $sqlq = "INSERT INTO user (fname, lname, username, password, admin) VALUES('".$fname."', '".$lname."', '".$username."', '".$hash."', '".$admin."');";
        $result = mysql_query($sqlq);
        if(!$result)
        {
            die("Fatal Error: Unable to insert into database");
        }
    }
?>
```

dbconn.php is shown as below

```
    <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$susername = "root";
$spassword = "123456";
$dbname = "alphara";
$conn = mysql_connect($servername, $susername, $spassword, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed with database! " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

?>
```

please help me with what is wrong. The echoed query runs successfully in phpmyadmin.

Comment: have you checked whether the DB connection created successfully?

Comment: Show the code of `dbconn.php`.

Comment: You need to provide much more information. Are you connected? What error did you get?

Comment: You can also try inserting manually through php mydmin window

Comment: Echo the insert query and run it in php myadmin window, so that you can identify whether error is from query or not.If not check the database connection

Comment: When you try to insert is this print any of die from both connection or query page.??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysql_connect will not take the database name. So try the following commands for connection.

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_connect_db($dbname, $link);
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this one in your dbconn.php

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', '123456');

mysql_select_db('alphara', $connection );
?>
```